# Erro ao atualizar AUTO INCREMENTO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Possuo o seguinte código:

```
$sql='ALTER TABLE tributos_prod AUTO_INCREMENT=:ultimo_id';
try {
    $query_delete=$conecta->prepare($sql);
    $query_delete->bindValue('ultimo_id', $ultimo_idTP+1, PDO: : PARAM_STR);
    $query_delete->execute();
}
catch(PDOException $erro) {
    echo'[ERRO] ao atualizar AUTO-INCREMENTO: '.$erro->getMessage();
    exit;
}
```

O seguinte erro é exibido:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or
>   access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near ''13'' at line 1

Já verifiquei o valor da variável `$ultimo_idTP`, utilizei `intval()` e está tudo certo, porém não estou conseguindo identificar o problema.

Comment: O valor de `$ultimo_idTP` seria 12? E por quê está passando o valor como *string* para a query SQL? Ele valor não deveria ser inteiro?

Answer (score 2):

Seu paramêtro está sendo enviado como string por gera o erro de sintaxe de acordo com a mensagem: `syntax to use near ''13''`.

Para resolver essa situação indique o terceiro argumento como inteiro (`PDO::PARAM_INT`).

Mude:

```
$query_delete->bindValue('ultimo_id', $ultimo_idTP+1, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Para:

```
$query_delete->bindValue('ultimo_id', $ultimo_idTP+1, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```